# Using Telnet Connection how to display and select the local file in Mac OS in Obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, local-files

I am new to Mac OS development. Want to display the local file in mac machine using Telnet Connection, and also how to display the connected machine local file using obj c. Spend couple of days but no idea. kindly help me how to do this concept. Thanks advance.

Comment: You have different questions here. You should Split into different post.

Answer (score 0):

To see local file executing telnet :

- use the escape character (ctrl-] or other control depending on your keyboard country)
- enter ! Followed by a ls command

> you can enter any command that can be executed on the local machine after !

For the distant machine, it depends to which server application you connected (telnet, ftp, mail,…) :

> Telnet is build to send/receive text between client (local host and server (distant host). With telnet you can connect to any port on the distant server. Sometimes you can interact, some other times you can’t.

Even seems simple, you can do a lot of thing with telnet connecting to a mail server and send mail from Santa Klaus .